# Change my login username (ID?)

Tags: support

When I originally joined Mathematica StackExchange I had an email address like XXXYYY@comcast.net that I that I use to login and that I would call ***my username***.

Since then I have changed my email account. I have modified the email in my profile but would like to also change my ***username***.

I can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: You like to have an other user name? You like to change Jack LaVigne to something else?

Comment: @Lou No, I am trying to change what is used as the name when I go to login.

Comment: Are you sure you want to allow this email address to be shown publicly?  You can edit the post and remove it (especially now that the problem is solved).

Comment: @Szabolcs , oh oh! Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

I followed Lou's advice and went to [Help Center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-do-i-change-my-openid-providers/114704#114704)

From there under **My Account** I clicked on *How do I add or remove login credentials from my account*.

From that page I scrolled to the bottom where the last sentence was ***To add or change a StackExchange OpenID***, *Please follow these instructions*.

On that page it showed that I should change my email under **Edit Profile & Settings** -> **Edit Profile**.

Then click on [/users/account-recover](https://stackoverflow.com/users/account-recovery) as if you had lost your password.

Set a password (the same or a new one) and you will get an email with a confirm link.

After confirming you will have the two user login names and can remove the old one from **Edit Profile & Settings** -> **My Logins**.

This was quite a tortuous path to follow but it worked.

Comment: Thank you for posting the solution for others to find. +1